# LDA Fit using Caret does not give Standard Deviation

Tags: r, caret, discriminant-analysis

I am following the steps outlined in [this tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/machine-learning-in-r-step-by-step/).

I have followed along and running into an issue at step 5.3. The output of the LDA model gives me all the expected information, except the Accuracy SD and Kappa SD are omitted.

Here is the code I ran and the results I got. I followed all steps of the tutorial, but left out some of the irrelevant code here.

```
library(caret)   

data(iris)
dataset <- iris

validation_index <- createDataPartition(dataset$Species, p=0.80, list=FALSE)
validation <- dataset[-validation_index,]
dataset <- dataset[validation_index,]
        
control <- trainControl(method="cv", number = 10)
metric <- "Accuracy"
# a) linear algorithms
set.seed(7)
fit.lda <- train(Species~., data=dataset, method="lda",metric=metric, trControl=control)
# b) nonlinear algorithms
# CART
set.seed(7)
fit.cart <- train(Species~., data=dataset, method="rpart",metric=metric, trControl=control)
# kNN
set.seed(7)
fit.knn <- train(Species~., data=dataset, method="knn",metric=metric, trControl=control)
# c) advanced algorithms
# SVM
set.seed(7)
fit.svm <- train(Species~., data=dataset, method="svmRadial",metric=metric, trControl=control)
# Random Forest
set.seed(7)
fit.rf <- train(Species~., data=dataset, method="rf",metric=metric, trControl=control)
results <- resamples(list(lda=fit.lda, cart=fit.cart, knn=fit.knn, svm=fit.svm, rf=fit.rf))
summary(results)

Call:
summary.resamples(object = results)

Models: lda, cart, knn, svm, rf 
Number of resamples: 10 

Accuracy 
          Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu. Max. NA's
lda  0.9166667 0.9375000 1.0000000 0.9750000 1.0000000    1    0
cart 0.7500000 0.8333333 0.9166667 0.9000000 0.9791667    1    0
knn  0.8333333 0.9166667 0.9583333 0.9416667 1.0000000    1    0
svm  0.8333333 0.9166667 0.9166667 0.9416667 1.0000000    1    0
rf   0.7500000 0.9166667 0.9166667 0.9250000 1.0000000    1    0

Kappa 
      Min. 1st Qu. Median   Mean 3rd Qu. Max. NA's
lda  0.875 0.90625 1.0000 0.9625 1.00000    1    0
cart 0.625 0.75000 0.8750 0.8500 0.96875    1    0
knn  0.750 0.87500 0.9375 0.9125 1.00000    1    0
svm  0.750 0.87500 0.8750 0.9125 1.00000    1    0
rf   0.625 0.87500 0.8750 0.8875 1.00000    1    0

print(fit.lda)
Linear Discriminant Analysis 

120 samples
  4 predictor
  3 classes: 'setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold) 
Summary of sample sizes: 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108, ... 
Resampling results:

  Accuracy  Kappa 
  0.975     0.9625
```

I tried all of this again with the `trainControl` function altered to be:

```
 control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number = 10, repeat=3)
```

These results were identical to my first pass. Does anyone know why the model isn't giving the Standard deviation?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still have this problem, but I was following the same tutorial and had the same issue.

Use:

`fit.lda$results`

To get the SD.

The answer was buried in the comment section:

https://machinelearningmastery.com/machine-learning-in-r-step-by-step/#comment-468434

Hopefully anyone who is also having this problem while following the tutorial will find it!